# cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wan't to change the size of the column from character(9) to character(12) by

```
ALTER TABLE product_based_award ALTER COLUMN name TYPE character(12);
```

But internally this column is used by a MView so it is not letting to alter the table and giving the following error.

> ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule

I have found two solutions for this, one is by dropping the mview and recreating it and the other is by updating pg_attribute.
But I cannot use these two options because our db is very complicated so updating pg_attribute can cause problems and cannot drop mview as well.

So is there any other best way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Snippets are only for html/css/javascript questions. Do not use snippets for other languages.

Comment: You can't change type if you cannot drop that view or update pg_attribute (not recommended anyway). You will __have__ to drop this view and those that depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

**updating `pg_attribute` is always critically bad idea**

to reduce time users wait for a new definition (assuming it loads data for significant time), you can use:

let s117 be old vie as:

```
t=# create materialized view s117 as select now()::timestamp(1);
SELECT 1
Time: 54.329 ms
```

change it:

```
t=# create materialized view s117_new as select now()::timestamp(2);
SELECT 1
Time: 64.024 ms
t=# begin;
BEGIN
Time: 0.099 ms
t=# drop materialized view s117;
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW
Time: 4.134 ms
t=# alter materialized view s117_new rename to s117;
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW
Time: 1.054 ms
t=# end;
COMMIT
Time: 49.256 ms
```

check:

```
t=# \d+ s117
                              Materialized view "public.s117"
 Column |              Type              | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+--------------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 now    | timestamp(2) without time zone |           | plain   |              |
View definition:
 SELECT now()::timestamp(2) without time zone AS now;
```

Comment: You can't use this view switching trick if both the old and new view are based on the *same* base table and the reason for wanting to replace the view is because you're wanting to change a column definition in the base table. You can't create the new view until the definition has changed and you can't change the definition until the old view has been dropped.